# What is the formal definition of a Cayley table?

Tags: magma, cayley-table

What is the formal definition of a Cayley table? I am not interested merely in Cayley tables for groups, I am interested in general Cayley tables for non-empty finite magmas. Also, another question is, does the ordering of the elements in the row and column have to be the same? Like, for example, if $a,b,c$ are the $3$ elements of a magma, can we have a Cayley table where the order of the row is $(a,b,c)$, while the order of the column is $(b,a,c)$? I would like it if there was a formalization of Cayley tables for non-empty finite magmas.

Comment: What is an informal definition?

Comment: If you are interested in visually picking out the center elements, you should list the elements in the same order along the rows and columns.